# How to flatten a list of list of dicts in pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have an object like

```
l = [
{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'obj2': [{'a': 3, 'b': 6}, {'a':4, 'b': 5}], 'obj': [{'x': 6, 'y': 'p'}, {'x': 10, 'y': 'q', 'z': 'qqq'}]},
{'id': 2, 'name': 'b', 'obj': [{'x': 10, 'y': 'r'}], 'obj2': [{'a': 9, 'i': 's'}]}
]
```

and I want to make it a dataframe like:

```
id   name    a    i    b    x    y   z
1     a      3         6    6    p 
1     a      3         6    10   q   qqq
1     a      4         5    6    p 
1     a      4         5    10   q   qqq 
2     b      9    s         10   r
```

Inside the l, all keys will be the same. But I may have different l with different key name and different amount of objects with lists inside l[0].
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for `pd.json_normalize`:

```
l = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'obj': [{'x': 6, 'y': 'p'}, {'x': 10, 'y': 'q', 'z': 'qqq'}]},
     {'id': 2, 'name': 'b', 'obj': [{'x': 10, 'y': 'r'}]}]

df = pd.json_normalize(l, 'obj', ['id', 'name'])
print(df)

# Output:
    x  y    z id name
0   6  p  NaN  1    a
1  10  q  qqq  1    a
2  10  r  NaN  2    b
```

**Udpate**:

> I want to use the same code for every object that has that structure type, but maybe the id,name,obj will be named differently

```
keys = list(l[0].keys())
df = pd.json_normalize(l, keys[-1], keys[:-1])
print(df)

# Output:
    x  y    z id name
0   6  p  NaN  1    a
1  10  q  qqq  1    a
2  10  r  NaN  2    b
```

Comment: what if the keys will not be always the same, i want to use the same code for every object that has that structure type,  but maybe the id,name,obj will be named differently

Comment: Can you update a sample with a such case, please?

Comment: Nothing crazy, but i need the same code to work even if i change the keys name. Your solution only works for some specific keys.
[  
{idq: 1, nameq: "a", objq: [{xq:6, yq:"p"}, {xq:10, yq:"q",zq:"qqq"}]},  
{idq: 2, nameq: "b", objq: [{xq:10, yq:"r"}]}  
]

Comment: For a same list, all the keys are the same, no?

Comment: @AndreiToader. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: for the same l(in your case) yes, all the keys are the same. Also, i don't know how many 'obj' are in an entry of l(but they will be the same amount for each entry of l).

Comment: How many 'obj' is really not a problem. The only problem is the key names and the length of the top level list. Here 3: `meta1 (id), meta2 (name) and record (obj)`. If you have this ordered structure, there is no problem.

Comment: yes, closer, but I also don't know how many meta columns or how many obj columns will be

Comment: Ok. I just need to know if the last column is the "obj" record?

Comment: i can not guarantee that it will be the last column or that it will be the only one that contains a list

Comment: Or maybe, It is the only one that contains a list?

Comment: no, there may be more that contain a list

Comment: So, explain me how do you determine who is who?

Comment: with isInstance(,list)

Comment: What is the output of `l = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'obj2': [{'a': 3, 'b': 6}], 'obj': [{'x': 6, 'y': 'p'}, {'x': 10, 'y': 'q', 'z': 'qqq'}]}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b', 'obj': [{'x': 10, 'y': 'r'}], 'obj2': [{'a': 9, 'i': 's'}]}]`. Update your post with this sample and create the expected output.

Comment: i updated the post and added more complexity to the input - @corralien